# Is there any way to use Google Calendar API in C# (WPF) with an async method?

Tags: c#, wpf, google-calendar-api

I am a beginer, this is the example from Google on how to officially implement the Google Calendar API using C#. The problem i have is that there is now way to use it with await/async, which means that my WPF application gets frozen when the requests gets made (?). I have looked on google for answers but could not find anything related to that specific issue.

```
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Calendar.v3;
using Google.Apis.Calendar.v3.Data;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using Google.Apis.Util.Store;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CalendarQuickstart
{
    class Program
    {
        // If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials
        // at ~/.credentials/calendar-dotnet-quickstart.json
        static string[] Scopes = { CalendarService.Scope.CalendarReadonly };
        static string ApplicationName = "Google Calendar API .NET Quickstart";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            UserCredential credential;

            using (var stream =
                new FileStream("credentials.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                // The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is created
                // automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first time.
                string credPath = "token.json";
                credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                    GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                    Scopes,
                    "user",
                    CancellationToken.None,
                    new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
                Console.WriteLine("Credential file saved to: " + credPath);
            }

            // Create Google Calendar API service.
            var service = new CalendarService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
            });

            // Define parameters of request.
            EventsResource.ListRequest request = service.Events.List("primary");
            request.TimeMin = DateTime.Now;
            request.ShowDeleted = false;
            request.SingleEvents = true;
            request.MaxResults = 10;
            request.OrderBy = EventsResource.ListRequest.OrderByEnum.StartTime;

            // List events.
            Events events = request.Execute();
            Console.WriteLine("Upcoming events:");
            if (events.Items != null && events.Items.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (var eventItem in events.Items)
                {
                    string when = eventItem.Start.DateTime.ToString();
                    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(when))
                    {
                        when = eventItem.Start.Date;
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1})", eventItem.Summary, when);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No upcoming events found.");
            }
            Console.Read();

        }
    }
}
```

I would need to add await/async but of course it doesn't work event if i make the method async and make it return a task because service.Events.List does not implemet GetAwaiter:

```
EventsResource.ListRequest request = await service.Events.List("primary"); // this is what i would need
```

I guess the alternative would be to use the pure REST api but is there really no other way?

Comment: Their documentation is astonishingly bad, but there appears to be an [`ExecuteAsync` method available.](https://googleapis.dev/dotnet/Google.Apis/latest/api/Google.Apis.Requests.ClientServiceRequest-1.html#Google_Apis_Requests_ClientServiceRequest_1_ExecuteAsync)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turn `Main` into `async`, avoid `.Result`

```csharp
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    //...
            credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                    GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                    Scopes,
                    "user",
                    CancellationToken.None,
                    new FileDataStore(credPath, true));
    // ...
}
```

To turn regular sync method into awaitable operation you can try `Task.Run()`

```csharp
EventsResource.ListRequest request = await Task.Run(() => service.Events.List("primary"));
```

Comment: You have no idea how much this helped me, thank you!